# What are these warnings in my console?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having the following error in my console.I don't know what are they.

```
2015-03-24 13:57:43.213 automobile[5454:530574] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174284880 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8e20]-(238)-[UIButton:0x12ee424c0'Retry']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174284740 V:[UIButton:0x12ee424c0'Retry']-(236)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8f00]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740aeb80 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8e20(50.66)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740aebe0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8e20]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x174185bd0 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740aee80 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8f00(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x1740aee20 _UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8f00.bottom == UIView:0x174185bd0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174289d30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x174185bd0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174284880 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x1741b8e20]-(238)-[UIButton:0x12ee424c0'Retry']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Anyone who know this?Any Help?

Comment: it is related to your autolayout. mean your constraint is not proper.

Comment: It tells you some of your constraints collide with each other, for example if you set width constraint but also top and bottom constraint to a view, this error will appear

Comment: how do I solve this and which constraints are not proper?can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have conflicting constraints on your views.
If you are using Interface Builder, I suggest your click on the Red or Yellow arrows in your VC scene and Xcode should give you more details as to what constraints are causing the issue.
You can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lbp8.png and here https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvFL.png how this should appear in Xcode.

I suggest you start by reconsidering the constraints and try to keep the minimum that satisfy your layout.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help but,i am not having any error in my Interface Builder.http://puu.sh/gNqpt/768480c577.png